# Python Regex: Find character within matched string

Tags: python, regex, replace, find

I want to use a regex in python to find all words which start with `\`.

Afterwards, the regex should look for a `[` within the matched word and then replace it with an underscore.

Here is an example:

```
input_string = SomeText \Word[0] Word[3] \SomeText[123] SomeText[10] SomeText
```

```
output_string = SomeText \Word_0] Word[3] \SomeText_123] SomeText[10] SomeText
```

The following python code replaces the square bracket with the underscore:

```py
output_string = re.sub(<regex>, '_', input_string)
```

I have written this regex to find words that start with `\` :

```
\\[^\s]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/d4YO9K/1

But now I don't know how to find the square bracket.

Can someone please contribute some ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You want to match:

```
r'((?:^| )\\\w*?\['
```

And replace with:

```
r'\1_`
```

which is whatever is in group 1 followed by a '_'.

1. `(` - Start of group 1
2. `(?:^| )` - Match start of string or a space
3. `\\` - Match a backslash
4. `\w*?` - Match 0 or more word characters non-greedily
5. `)` - End of group 1
6. `\[` - Match a [

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kKNEji/1/)

Note that you should not be naming your variable `input`, which is the name of a built-in function.

```python
import re

s = 'SomeText \Word[0] Word[3] \SomeText[123] SomeText[10] SomeText'

output = re.sub(r'((?:^| )\\\w*?)\[', r'\1_', s)
print(output)
```

Prints:

```
SomeText \Word_0] Word[3] \SomeText_123] SomeText[10] SomeText
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and your feedback! Your solution fully works.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that takes the match object and returns the replacement string:

```
def rep(m):
    return m.group(0).replace("[", "_")
```

And pass it as the the replacement parameter to `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(r"\\\S+", rep, "abc \\xyz[0] def")
'abc \\xyz_0] def'
```